# Find the sum reduction issue with size of thread in CUDA

Tags: cuda, reduction

In previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654754/how-to-find-the-sum-of-array-in-cuda-by-reduction), I asked about how to calculate sum of an array with reduction. Now I have a new problem, with larger image, my result is not correct, it change every time I run.
I tested with 96*96 image size [array sample](http://pastebin.com/Sddds9sX)

First time result: 28169.046875

Second time result: 28169.048828

Expected result:  28169.031250

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__  void calculate_threshold_kernel(float * input, float * output)
{

   int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int t = threadIdx.x;
   __shared__ float partialSum[256];
   partialSum[t] = input[idx];
   __syncthreads();

   for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride *= 2)
   {
       if (t % (2 * stride) == 0)
           partialSum[t] += partialSum[t + stride];

       __syncthreads();
   }

   if (t == 0)
   {
       atomicAdd(output,partialSum[0]);
   }

}
int main( void )
{

    float *d_array, *d_output,*h_input, *h_output;
    int img_height = 96;
    int img_width = 96;
    int input_elements = img_height * img_width;

    h_input = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * input_elements);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(d_output, 0, sizeof(float));
    h_output = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array, input_elements*sizeof(float));

    float array[] = {[array sample]};
    for (int i = 0; i < input_elements; i++)
    {
        h_input[i] = array[i];
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_array, h_input, input_elements*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        dim3 blocksize(256);
        dim3 gridsize(input_elements/blocksize.x);

        calculate_threshold_kernel<<<gridsize,blocksize>>>(d_array, d_output);

        cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        printf("Sum from GPU = %f\n", *h_output);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer from Kangshiyin is correct about floating point accuracy and floating point arithmetic being non-commutative, he is not correct about the reason behind the results differing from one run to the other.

- Floating point arithmetic is non-commutative, this means operations performed in different order can return different results. For example `(((a+b)+c)+d)` may be slightly different than `((a+b)+(c+d))` for certain values of `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`. But both these results should not vary from run to run.
- Your result vary between different runs because `atomicAdd` results in the order of additions being different. Using double also does not guarantee that the results will be the same between different runs.
- There are ways to implement parallel reduction without atomicAdd as the final step (ex: use a second kernel launch to add partial sums from the first launch) which can provide consistent (yet slightly different from CPU) results.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I will change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`float` has a limited precision up to 7 demical digits as explained here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

<s>The result changes because operations on `float` are non-commutative and you are using parallel reduction.</s>

The result changes because operations on `float` are non-commutative and you are using `atomicAdd()`, which can not keep the order of additions.

You could use `double` instead if you want more accurate result.

Comment: Thanks you, but as I know, the  **atomicAdd()**   not support  **double** right ??

Comment: There's an implementation in cuda documentation, which uses `atomicCAS()`. You could use it. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions